# -215:Assertion failed

Tags: python, opencv, warnings, assertion

I am using vscode and this is my code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**and it is giving me this error**

> [ WARN:0] global
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp
>   (674) SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB
>
> terminating async callback
>
> [ERROR:0] global
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (193)
>   cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(DSHOW): raised unknown C++ exception!
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "c:/Users/VVA/Desktop/demo.py", line 8, in
>
> ```
> gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
> ```
>
> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function
>   'cv::cvtColor'

Comment: Did none of [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bopencv%5D+python+%22-215%22+cvtcolor+is%3Aq) have an answer for you? What research have you done to resolve this problem before posting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this error because your `VideoCapture(0)` is not returning the camera object and because of that, `cap.read()` is not able to read anything. If you will print `ret` just after `ret, frame=cap.read()`, you will be getting output as **False**

Now, the solution to this problem is very simple.

Change

```
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

to

```
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```

And then try running this through a `.py` file from command prompt. Sometimes jupyter notebook shows errors.

[image: CAP_DSHOW Explanation from opencv documentation]

for detailed information:
[OpenCV Flags for video I/O](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gga023786be1ee68a9105bf2e48c700294dab6ac3effa04f41ed5470375c85a23504)

Answer (score 0):

It showing that  the size of the   `frame` is 0. When you read from

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Check if you do have `frame` is loaded or not.

Comment: No bro i change the the webcam input and also tried to add and image but it's still giving me the same error